# What fees and other costs are associated with Moneybookers withdrawals‎ in China?

Tags: international, online-payment, international-trading

What fees and other costs are associated with Moneybookers withdrawals‎ in China?

Answer (score 1):

[I don't see](http://www.moneybookers.com/app/help.pl?s=fees&fee_currency=USD) any withdrawal options for China.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you will link your Visa or Master card to your moneybookers account and will withdraw money from account on your card, it will cost you standard 1.9%.